# Efficient algorithm for only keeping distant values

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of values which might look something like this: `[500,501,809,702,808,807,703,502,499]` and I would like to only keep the first instance of each number within a certain distance. In other words, I'd like to get the list: `[500,809,702]` because the other numbers are within a certain distance from those numbers. So it would keep 500, skip 501 because it's too close, keep 809 because it's far away from the already selected values, keep 702, etc.

Here's my current solution:

```
vals = ... #the original data
result = []
tolerance = 50
for i in vals:
    if not len(np.where(np.abs(result - i) < tolerance)[0]):
        results.append(i)
```

This works fine, but it's too slow for my purposes (I'm dealing with 2.4 million elements in the list). Is there an efficient solution to this problem? Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I need to keep the **first** element of each group, not the smallest element (i.e. `[499, 702, 807]` would not be a valid result in the above example), so sorting it might not help so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vals = [500,501,809,702,808,807,703,502,499]
close_set = set()
tolerance = 5
result = []
for e in vals:
    if e in close_set:
        continue
    else:
        result.append(e)
        close_set.update([*range(e-tolerance, e+tolerance+1)])

print(result)  # [500, 809, 702]
```

This should be pretty fast (I tested it on a list of 1,000,000 elements and it took ~3 seconds). For each element in the list, you check to see if a close value has been seen before by checking for membership in the set of close numbers, which is O(1). If it's not, you add it to your results and then update the set of close numbers.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! For python2, I just changed the second to last line to `close_set.update(range(e-tolerance, e+tolerance+1))`

Comment: @jstein123 If you want to make it compatible with both, wrap that range in a `list()`

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use a `SortedSet` from http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html.

Before inserting an element you check `irange_key` all values within `+- tolerance`.  If nothing is there, then add this element.

This solution should be at least an order of magnitude faster than the `close_set` approach already suggested, and an order of magnitude better as well on memory usage.  Plus it will work for floats as well as integers if you should need that.

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: 'SortedSet' object has no attribute 'irange_key'`

EDIT: solved it by converting it to a SortedKeyList first. Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm implementing this incorrectly, this seems quite more inefficient than the other posted solution since order matters for my solution.

Comment: How inefficient? I have a solution around 2x slower than that of @MoxieBall based on the order preserving dicts in python3.6 . I did not post because it was slower than the set solution.